# Tkinter: Redirect stdout to read-only Text

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I am creating a GUI with Python Tkinter.

I am able to redirect stdout to a text field, but not sure how to make it read only (with no editing allowed from user).

Redirect stdout script so far:

```
class IORedirector(object):
   '''A general class for redirecting I/O to this Text widget.'''
   def __init__(self,text_area):
      self.text_area = text_area
class StdoutRedirector(IORedirector):
   '''A class for redirecting stdout to this Text widget.'''
   def write(self,message):
      self.text_area.insert("insert", message)

self.text_box = Text(self, wrap = 'word')
self.text_box.grid(column = 0, row = 1, columnspan = 2, sticky = 'NSWE', padx = 5, pady = 5)
sys.stdout = StdoutRedirector(self.text_box)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is actually very easy to do.

add 2 lines within class StdoutRedirector:

```
class StdoutRedirector(IORedirector):
   '''A class for redirecting stdout to this Text widget.'''
   def write(self,message):
      self.text_area.config(state = "normal")
      self.text_area.insert("insert", message)
      self.text_area.config(state = "disabled")
```